# Installation issue in EOS

Tags: cleos, nodeos, block-producer

I have cloned the EOS repository and trying to start the script using the following command.

```
  `sh ./eosio_build.sh`
```

But it raises the following issue?

```
   ./eosio_build.sh: 33: ./eosio_build.sh: Bad substitution
   ./eosio_build.sh: 43: ./eosio_build.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `./eosio_build.sh darwin`

Run command without `sh`

Suggestion:

Use docker image of eos instead of compiling from scratch. For more details, refer the following link
https://www.eosdocs.io/dappdevelopment/software/docker/